# Error converting byte array to PublicKey java

Tags: java, public-key

while trying to convert byte[] array to PublicKey I'm getting an error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: java.security.InvalidKeyException: IOException: short read of DER octet string
>       at sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyFactory.engineGeneratePublic(Unknown Source)
>       at java.security.KeyFactory.generatePublic(Unknown Source)

This is part of code that gives me this error:

```
byte[] publicKeyBytes = keystring.getBytes();
KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
EncodedKeySpec publicKeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(publicKeyBytes);
PublicKey publicKey2 = keyFactory.generatePublic(publicKeySpec);
```

Checked before, byte[] array that i'm getting from string is the same as the original one.
Thanks

Comment: How do you get `keystring`? `X590EncodedKeySpec` requires DER format, which you'll get via `publickey.getEncoded()`.

Comment: I'm getting it over tcp, so at the "server" i'm converting from publickey.getEncoded() to string, than sending it. At the client it's keystring that i'm receiving

Comment: How are you converting it from encoded to `String`? Depending on character set you might change the bytes. base64 might be a suitable encoding of the bytes in String-form.

Comment: byte[] publicKeyBytes = pair.getPublic().getEncoded();
String keystring=new String(publicKeyBytes);

Answer (score -1, accepted):

According to your comments you convert the bytes of the encoded public key directly to `String` using the default encoding, which will for sure drop/replace some of the bytes. See the JavaDoc for [`new String(bytes[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28byte[]%29).

So the content of `pair.getPublic().getEncoded()` and `keystring.getBytes()` won't be the same.

Use a suitable transport encoding, like [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64). On Java 8, you can use [`java.util.Base64`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html) for that, on older platforms the [Apache Commons Codec's `Base64`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html) class can be used.